# TypeError: Object of type Vehicle is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django

When I try to filter my model I got this error:

```
TypeError: Object of type Vehicle is not JSON serializable
```

My model:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    driver_id = models.ForeignKey(Driver,on_delete=CASCADE,unique=True,null=True, blank=True)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    plate_number = models.CharField(max_length=10,validators = [validate_plate_numberLATIN,validate_plate_numberCYRYLLIC], unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=NOW)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=NOW)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.make
```

my get view that generate an error

```
   def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        vehicles = Vehicle.objects.values('driver_id','make','model','plate_number','created_at','updated_at')
        if request.GET.get('with_drivers') == 'yes':
            vehicles = Vehicle.objects.exclude(driver_id__isnull=True)
        data = {
            'vehicles' : list(vehicles)
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: Provide the code that generated the error (where you filter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is because when you filter, you set `vehicles` to be the filtered queryset. When you call `list` on this queryset, you get the list of `Vehicle` models, which are not serializable.

When you don't filter, you are getting the specified `values`, and that returns you a dict (which is serializable).

So, you can just get the values after filtering:

```
def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
    vehicles = Vehicle.objects.all()
    if request.GET.get('with_drivers') == 'yes':
        vehicles = vehicles.exclude(driver_id__isnull=True)
        
    vehicles = vehicles.values(
        'driver_id',
        'make',
        'model',
        'plate_number',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    )

    data = {
        'vehicles' : list(vehicles)
    }

    return JsonResponse(data)
```